# Preventing a Spring @RequestMapping from loading out of a dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**Background**

I have a number of small, microservice-type applications which all run in Spring Boot using @RestController & @RequestMapping. As they are normally talking to each other, I made each one available over HTTP but I can also include each JAR in other projects to directly access their functionality. This has become an issue though; as the mappings from a JAR are being mapped in the host application when it starts... which in my case would be a security issue.

***Is their a way to prevent certain mappings from being loaded by Spring?***

Comment: I assume it's because both your dependency and your current application share the same package name. That means your application will component scan your JAR as well, effectively creating request mappings for those dependencies as well. The easiest solution would be to rename your packages to have a separate package name for each library.

Comment: I will give this a go and report back; sounds about right though, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to make this an official answer and I will accept it if it fixes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe that I have used from time to time:

- First split the jar into two (or more) separate jar files and only include the dependencies that are necessary, i.e. omit the one that is exposing the security issue.
- Make sure that the jars use different package names and that the package names are not nested between jars.
- Finally, you can create config in each dependency that is responsible for its own component scan, see below.

In your dependency jar, create a config class:

```
package com.example.dependency;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.dependency")
public class DependencyConfig {
    // possibly return other @Bean declarations
}
```

In the Spring Boot app (in another jar) you can `@Import` the dependency configuration:

```
package com.example.application;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(DependencyConfig.class)
public class MainApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args); 
    }
}
```

The benefit is that the `MainApplication` does not need to know which packages of the dependency it needs to scan, it is an implementation detail hidden inside the dependency jar.